# How to view available commands on a remote server

Tags: else-heart-break

I know how to connect to other servers and I am aware that you can interact remotely with them, but is it possible to view what they can do? Do you just have to do commands and hope or is there a way to actually see what they can do, something like remoteServer.GetCommands()?